# Android - Enabling javascript in Webview makes app force close

Tags: android, webview

I have an app, where a Webview pops up in a dialog. I need Javascript enabled, but it causes the app to force close.
I have tried putting in many locations, including OnCreate and when the button to open the Webview dialog is pressed. It still causes the app to force close. Any ideas why?
Code and log below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
//import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
//import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
 //import android.widget.Button;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.almondmendoza.R;
import com.almondmendoza.drawings.brush.Brush;
//import com.almondmendoza.drawings.brush.CircleBrush;
import com.almondmendoza.drawings.brush.PenBrush;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;



public class DrawingActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{
    private DrawingSurface drawingSurface;
    private DrawingPath currentDrawingPath;
    private Paint currentPaint;

    private ImageButton redoBtn;
    private ImageButton undoBtn;
    WebView webview;
    private Brush currentBrush;





    private File APP_FILE_PATH = new File("/sdcard/TutorialForAndroidDrawings");

LinearLayout calendarLayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawing_activity);

      calendarLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.calendarLayout);


webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      



        setCurrentPaint();
        currentBrush = new PenBrush();

        drawingSurface = (DrawingSurface) findViewById(R.id.drawingSurface);
        drawingSurface.setOnTouchListener(this);
        drawingSurface.previewPath = new DrawingPath();
        drawingSurface.previewPath.path = new Path();
        drawingSurface.previewPath.paint = getPreviewPaint();

        redoBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redoBtn);
        undoBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.undoBtn);

        redoBtn.setEnabled(false);
        undoBtn.setEnabled(false);


        //SEEKBAR THICKNESS CHANGE
        //
        //
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekValue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(progress);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

            }
        });
        }
    //END SEEKBAR THICKNESS





    private void setCurrentPaint(){
        currentPaint = new Paint();
        currentPaint.setDither(true);
        currentPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);


    }

    private Paint getPreviewPaint(){
        final Paint previewPaint = new Paint();
        previewPaint.setColor(0xFFC1C1C1);
        previewPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        previewPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        previewPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        previewPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        return previewPaint;
    }




    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            drawingSurface.isDrawing = true;

            currentDrawingPath = new DrawingPath();
            currentDrawingPath.paint = currentPaint;
            currentDrawingPath.path = new Path();
            currentBrush.mouseDown(currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            currentBrush.mouseDown(drawingSurface.previewPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


        }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            drawingSurface.isDrawing = true;
            currentBrush.mouseMove( currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() );
            currentBrush.mouseMove(drawingSurface.previewPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


        }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){


            currentBrush.mouseUp(drawingSurface.previewPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            drawingSurface.previewPath.path = new Path();
            drawingSurface.addDrawingPath(currentDrawingPath);

            currentBrush.mouseUp( currentDrawingPath.path, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() );

            undoBtn.setEnabled(true);
            redoBtn.setEnabled(false);

        }

        return true;
    }




    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){


        //CALENDAR
        case R.id.calendarBtn:
            calendarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.closeCalBtn:
            calendarLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.calculatorBtn:
             Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DrawingActivity.this);
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             View vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.webviewdialog, null);
             dialog.setContentView(vi);
             dialog.setTitle("Calculator");
             dialog.setCancelable(true);
             WebView wb = (WebView) vi.findViewById(R.id.webview);
             wb.loadUrl("http://mitchsamuels.com/calculator.html");
             System.out.println("..loading url..");
             dialog.show();

            break;






            //COLORS
            case R.id.colorRedBtn:
                SeekBar seekBarRed = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
                currentPaint = new Paint();
                currentPaint.setDither(true);
                currentPaint.setColor(0xCC990000);
                currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(seekBarRed.getProgress());
            break;
            case R.id.colorBlueBtn:
                SeekBar seekBarBlue = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
                currentPaint = new Paint();
                currentPaint.setDither(true);
                currentPaint.setColor(0xCC3333FF);
                currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(seekBarBlue.getProgress());
            break;
            case R.id.colorGreenBtn:
                SeekBar seekBarGreen = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
                currentPaint = new Paint();
                currentPaint.setDither(true);
                currentPaint.setColor(0xCC00CC00);
                currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(seekBarGreen.getProgress());
            break;
            case R.id.colorWhiteBtn:
                SeekBar seekBarWhite = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
                currentPaint = new Paint();
                currentPaint.setDither(true);
                currentPaint.setColor(0xCCFFFFFF);
                currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(seekBarWhite.getProgress());
            break;
            case R.id.eraserBtn:
                currentPaint = new Paint();
                currentPaint.setDither(true);
                currentPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
                currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
               currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(70);
            break;



            //UNDO/REDO/SAVE

            case R.id.undoBtn:
                drawingSurface.undo();
                if( drawingSurface.hasMoreUndo() == false ){
                    undoBtn.setEnabled( false );
                }
                redoBtn.setEnabled( true );
            break;

            case R.id.redoBtn:
                drawingSurface.redo();
                if( drawingSurface.hasMoreRedo() == false ){
                    redoBtn.setEnabled( false );
                }

                undoBtn.setEnabled( true );
            break;
            case R.id.saveBtn:
                final Activity currentActivity  = this;
                Handler saveHandler = new Handler(){
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Image Saved!");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Your note has been saved in your gallery.");
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                } ;


               new ExportBitmapToFile(this,saveHandler, drawingSurface.getBitmap()).execute();
            break;

        }
    }





    private static final int REQUEST_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;
    private static final int ABOUT_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 5;
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_EMAIL = null;
    //private static final TextView TextView = null;



//CREATE MENU
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, REQUEST_MENU_ID, 0, "Request Features").setShortcut('5', 'c');
        menu.add(0, ABOUT_MENU_ID, 0, "About").setShortcut('4', 's');

        return true;
    }




    //MENU SELECTIONS
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {



            case ABOUT_MENU_ID:
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DrawingActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
                dialog.setTitle("About Jot Notes");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);



                dialog.show();

                return true;
            case REQUEST_MENU_ID:
                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"samuels.mitch@gmail.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Jot Notes");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Dear Jot developer,");
                //context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                  //Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                  //sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Jot Notes");
                  //sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"Samuels.mitch@gmail.com"});
                 // sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Dear Jot Developer,");
                  //sendIntent.setType(CONTENT_TYPE_EMAIL);
                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Please Select an Application"));

                  return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }









    private class ExportBitmapToFile extends AsyncTask<Intent,Void,Boolean> {
        private Context mContext;
        private Handler mHandler;
        private Bitmap nBitmap;

        public ExportBitmapToFile(Context context,Handler handler,Bitmap bitmap) {
            mContext = context;
            nBitmap = bitmap;
            mHandler = handler;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Intent... arg0) {
            try {
                if (!APP_FILE_PATH.exists()) {
                    APP_FILE_PATH.mkdirs();
                }

                final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(APP_FILE_PATH + "/myAwesomeDrawing.png"));
                nBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                return true;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //mHandler.post(completeRunnable);
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {
            super.onPostExecute(bool);
            if ( bool ){
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```